# Android Service which displays toast message of KeyPress

Tags: android, service, toast, background-service

How to display toast message from android service which is running at the background? Basically I need to display all the KeyPress actions to be displayed as a toast message from background running service (Over all apps / Home).

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent KEvent)
{
    int keyaction = KEvent.getAction();
    if(keyaction == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {

       int keycode = KEvent.getKeyCode();
       Toast.makeText(this," KEYCODE=" + keycode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(KEvent);
}
```

I am using the above set of code to toast the keypress.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your service is running on a background thread, you'll have to use runOnUIThread or a handler like below:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // toast here
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you help me in understanding better? I am a beginner

Comment: A toast must be called on a UI thread.  If you have a service running on a background thread, you need to make the toast call from within a runnable that is running on the main thread.  The code above will do that for you or the other option is to use Androids runOnUIThread() method.